# jQuery does work with IE on different environments but one IE not?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have a VDI development environment (Wamp) with IE11. I have developed a screen on this environment with PHP and jQuery (jQuery2.1.3.min.js/Fixedheader.js/Table2Excel.js). Works all fine.

Now it is installed on the development-server (http://dev...etc), another environment. Later it will be installed on the acceptance-server and production-server.

When I run the same report with IE from my client-laptop than I get the following error's in the console:

- The property or Method addEventListener is not supported by this object
- jQuery is not defined (fixedheader.min.js)
- jQuery is not defined (table2excel.min.js)
- The value of the property $ null or not defined and no functieobject.

If I run this report from my client-laptop with FF, works fine!!
If I run this report on the development-server self, with IE (http://localhost/...), works fine. Not any problem.

So in my opinion it can't be a coding issue.

I have been comparing the IE internet options between my client laptop and my VDI IE. Not any difference!

What else is left? What can be the reason that on one environment the IE is not loading the jQuery and on the other environment it works fine? What else can it be if it is not the Internet Options of IE?

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of your scripts; that could be causing the console errors to fire.

Make sure jQuery is loaded before fixedheader.min.js and table2excel.min.js - also try and postpone loading of those scripts till the footer if they aren't already. You could try and update jQuery from 2.1.3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, but the thing is I don't understand it.

I have checked with F12 - development tools. I saw that the browser documentmodus was set on 7 (default). I suppose that it means use/emulate IE7. I do not understand who is doing this, were does it come from?
I found this line on stackoverflow and I have add this line.:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

We did have already this line in the code:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And as document type we have only this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Is that not good and must it be changed for example to this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Does that make any sense?

Thanks,

Nico